# Query key value in different columns from Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I gather analytics with Firebase Analytics which I linked to Google BigQuery.

I have the following data in BigQuery (unnecessary columns/rows are left off, the dataset looks similar to https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/firebase-analytics-sample-data:ios_dataset.app_events_20160607?tab=preview):

```
| event_dim.name | event_dim.params.key | event_dim.params.value.string_value |
|----------------|----------------------|-------------------------------------|
| read_post      | post_id              | p_100                               |
|                | group_id             | g_1                                 |
|                | user_id              | u_1                                 |
| open_group     | post_id              | p_200                               |
|                | group_id             | g_2                                 |
|                | user_id              | u_1                                 |
| open_group     | post_id              | p_300                               |
|                | group_id             | g_1                                 |
|                | user_id              | u_3                                 |
```

I want to query the following data:

- event name
- user id
- group id

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT
  event_dim.name,
  FIRST(IF(event_dim.params.key = "user_id", event_dim.params.value.string_value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD user_id,
  FIRST(IF(event_dim.params.key = "group_id", event_dim.params.value.string_value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD group_id
FROM
  [xxx:xxx_IOS.app_events_20161102]
LIMIT
  1000
```

The problem with the above query is that the aggregate function `FIRST` will give the wrong result because the `SELECT` statements with a `WITHIN` modifier will return a list of results. The `FIRST` function will only give the correct result in case of the first row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options") you can do:

```
SELECT
  event_dim.name,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(params)
   WHERE key = 'user_id') AS user_id,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(params)
   WHERE key = 'group_id') AS group_id
FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_20160607`,
  UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
LIMIT 1000;
```

If you only want rows that have both `'user_id'` and `'group_id'`, you can filter out the NULL values:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    event_dim.name,
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(params)
     WHERE key = 'user_id') AS user_id,
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(params)
     WHERE key = 'group_id') AS group_id
  FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_20160607`,
    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
)
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL AND group_id IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Okay, that seems to work perfectly! The data is shown in a different order than the preview, but that's not a big deal.
Would you know by any chance how I could add multiple tables (with the same schema) to this query?

Comment: Sure, you may be interested in [wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables) or, instead of `FROM MyTable`, you can do `FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable UNION ALL SELECT * FROM MyOtherTable UNION ALL ...)`. The [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#comma_operator_with_tables) has a couple of examples with `UNION ALL`, too.

Comment: Hah, I was just reading about wildcard tables. That's a great feature! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you, I was tearing my hair out trying to get my columns out this way. Really helped!